# Button Size for Google tv app

Tags: android, button, resolution, google-tv

Can any one please tell me what should be the buttons Resolution for google tv app, that should look not too small on google tv screen. I need exact resolution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google TV runs in XHDPI mode. (A density of 2.0). Standard buttons are 48dp. So 96 pixels would be correct. Buttons look very reasonable at 48dp/96px.

That covers 1080p. Everything gets rescaled in 720p. Google does not seem to recommend generating TVDPI bitmaps. You just lay it out at 1080p, and let Google TV downscale if it's running 720p. Layout appears identical. Bitmaps suffer some damage, but it's not terrible. I haven't done any 720p bitmaps.

Comment: Looking at this answer in retrospect, it's not quite specific enough. A standard Action Bar button is laid out on a 48dp grid, which is composed of a 32-db icon + 8dp padding. I use the 32dp-content on a 48dp design grid throughout my app, and it looks very reasonable. A lot is made of the "ten foot experience" by Google and Microsoft. The "ten foot experience" doesn't allow quite the same information density as a 7" tablet, but is a walk in the park compared to the 3.5" experience. 48dp comes from touch-slop on small displays, but the result is very "Android", even on google tv.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a huge button use 300dp by 150dp

Your question is very ambiguous and hard to answer because you have not provided any real context. Consider rewording with more detail.

Google TV has a resolution of 960x540 DP.

If you are asking about pixel resolution then there are two modes you need to consider.
720p results in 1280x720 pixels but you will need to account for over scan (usually 5%)
1080p results in 1920x1080 pixels (again you will need to account for over scan)

You may want to look at this post: http://code.neenbedankt.com/dpi-hell

Comment: thanks for the hint, infact i just started making a google tv app and i nneded to get an idea about the normal buttons and widgets dimensions,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by normal but it is an Android device with the screen dimensions indicated. A good source to find out how others are sizing their buttons and widgets is the Google TV Code Samples. https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples